# How I can integrate Hilt with Compose functions?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm developing a project using Kotlin with Compose.
I have three modules: app, features and navigation. Only app linked to other modules.
Tried to send Bottom screens to navigation module using interface.

it is working wery well without Hilt, but got an error when added Hilt.

`incompatible types: Function0 cannot be converted to Function2<? super Composer,? super Integer,Unit> return new DefaultScreen(bottomScreen)`
is it possible to add Compose functions to hilt?

```
interface Screens {
    val bottomScreen: @Composable () -> Unit
}

class DefaultScreen @Inject constructor(
    override val bottomScreen: @Composable () -> Unit

) : Screens
```

```
val maps: Map<String, Screens> = mapOf(
  "First" to DefaultScreen { FirstScreen() },
  "Second" to  DefaultScreen { SecondScreen() }
)
NavigateApp(maps)
```